# Multiply each column by a column next to that column and create single column

Tags: python, pandas, dataset

I have kind of very specific requirement, but one might be able to re-use the knowledge of this question for his/her scenario.

I have following dataframe which contains value columns and relay column related to that value column next to each value column. I need to multiply each value column by it's next column and write the result into a new dataset. (this is kind of summary). there are many columns, so it is very difficult to multiply these columns manually.

What is the best way to do this

```
      A       B    C      D  ....
      12.23   0    43.34  1  ....
      78.56   1    67.78  0  ....
```

Result

```
      X      Y 
      0      43.34  ....
      78.56  0      ....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
out=pd.DataFrame(df[df.columns[::2]].values*df[df.columns[1::2]].values,columns=['X','Y'])
print(out)
```

---

```
       X      Y
0   0.00  43.34
1  78.56   0.00
```

Comment: Is this limited for 2 columns?

Comment: @Malintha not really, but as per the naming convention of the column goes, you can either assign the column name as `df.columns[::2]` or the other way, else you need to have a list of column names for assigning custom columns in the dataframe constructor. :)